# Rails ActiveRecord conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, rails-activerecord

Is there a way to create a condition like this?

```
@products = Product.find(:all,
  :limit => 5,
  :conditions => { :products => { :locale => 'en', :id NOT '1' }, :tags => { :name => ['a','b']})
```

I would like to list all products not including product 1.
Thx.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Rails 3**

Use [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem.

```
Product.where(
  :products => { :locale => 'en', :id.not_in => '1' }, 
  :tags => { :name => ['a','b']}
).limit(5)
```

**Rails 2**

Use [AR Extensions](http://github.com/zdennis/ar-extensions/tree/master/ar-extensions/) for this. It supports the following condition modifiers:

```
* _lt => less than
* _gt => greater than
* _lte => less than or equal to
* _gte => greater than or equal to
* _ne => not equal to
* _not => not equal to
```

Now you can rewrite your query as follows:

```
@products = Product.find(:all,
  :limit => 5,
  :joins => [:tags],
  :conditions => { :locale => 'en', :id_not => '1', :tags => { :name => ['a','b']}
)
```

Answer (score 9):

It should be something like this. The original query wasn't really clear, adapt it to your needs.

```
@products = Product.find(:all,
  :limit => 5,
  :conditions => ["locale = ? AND id <> ? AND tags.name IN (?)", "en", 1, ['a','b'],
  :joins => "tags"
)
```

Comment: I'm looking for "no-string" solution, as hash {...}.

Comment: It doesn't exist a solution using Hash.

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to use the merge_conditions which turns the hash conditions into a string. Then you can add on whatever you want or call merge_conditions again with other options.

```
hash_conditions = {:category => 'computers'}
conditions = Product.merge_conditions(hash_conditions) + ' AND products.id NOT IN(1139) '
products = Product.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Rails 3.2.9**

---

### Controller

```
  @products = Product.english_but_not(1).with_tags('a','b').limit(5)
```

---

### Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :locale
  has_many :tags
  scope :english, -> { where(:locale => 'en') }
  scope :except_id, ->(id) { where(arel_table[:id].not_eq(id)) }
  scope :english_but_not, ->(id) { english.except_id(id) }
  scope :with_tags, ->(*names) { includes(:tags).where(:tags => {:name => names}) }
end
```