# ArgumentError on model query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, arguments

I'm using ruby 2.1.5p273, Rails 4.2.3 but have upgraded from much older versions recently.

I'm getting a "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" error on this line from the **Phone** model:

```
Phone.all(:joins => :phone_page, :conditions => [query, condition_values], :order => "date")
```

**query** and **condition_values** are present.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Is there upgraded syntax that should be used here instead? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails ActiveRecord conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333970/rails-activerecord-conditions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax changed in Rails 4. Now you are supposed to do as following:

```
Phone.joins(:phone_page).where(query, condition_values).order(:date)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

.all doesn't take arguments, see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b1879124a82b34168412ac699cf6f654e005c4d6/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L24). Product.find(:all, your-arguments)

[See related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333970/rails-activerecord-conditions)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The essential part of the answer was that .all doesnt take arguments

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite this query. One of the solutions is:

```
Phone.joins(:phone_page).where(query, condition_values).order('date')
```

Also take a look at ActiveRecord querying interface documentation here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html